# HTTP Post method returnin status code 404

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404, spring-restcontroller

My maven project using hibernate apache cxf spring and backbone.js
I'm trying save data to table with post method.But I always get 404 as response code.

my index.html code

```
    var departmentNameModel=Backbone.Model.extend({

        urlRoot:"/rest/departmentName",
        defaults:{
            departmentName:"Boş"
        }

    });

    var departmentNameView=Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName:"tr",
        template:"<td><span>{{departmentName}}</span><input type='text' value='{{departmentName}}' style='width:190px; display:none;' /><button class='btn btn-danger btn-mini' style='float:right;'>Sil</button> </td>",
        model: {},
        events:{
            "dblclick span":"duzenlemeModu",
            "blur input":"duzenle",
            "click button":"sil"
        },

        duzenlemeModu:function(){
            this.$el.find("input").css("display","");
            this.$el.find("span").css("display","none");
        },

        duzenle:function(){
            this.model.save("departmentName",this.$el.find("input").val());

            this.render();
            this.$el.find("input").css("display","none");
            this.$el.find("span").css("display","");
        },

        sil:function(){
            this.model.destroy();
            this.remove();
        },

        render: function(){
            var html=  Mustache.to_html(this.template,this.model.toJSON());

            $(this.el).html(html);
            return this;
        }


    });
    var AppView=Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("body"),
        events:{
            "keypress #departmentName":"kaydet"
        },   
        kaydet:function(evt){
            if(evt.keyCode!==13) return;
            var departmentNameeModel=new departmentNameModel();
            departmentNameeModel.set("departmentName",$("#departmentName").val());
            departmentNameeModel.save();
            var departmentNameeView=new departmentNameView();

            departmentNameeView.model=departmentNameeModel;
            $("table").append(departmentNameeView.render().el);
            $("#departmentName").val("");

        }

    });

    var apppView = new AppView();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my cxfservlet url-pattern is /rest/*

My resource/department some code part

```
    @Component
@Path("/department")
public class DepartmentResource {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public DepartmentDTO save(DepartmentDTO dto) {
          //dto.setDepartmentName();

          return departmentService.save(dto);
        }
```

I shared my error on Screenshot.Sorry my english not good.I hope i could tell you the problem.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: You are using the Spring Framework without the MVC module?

Comment: yes, i am not using SpringMVC i am using Backbone.js for layered architecture

Answer (score 0):

At the very least I can see that your @Path("/department") and  urlRoot:"/rest/departmentName" does not match. That may be the reason why you are getting 404 (Not Found) error message. Try to match urlRoot and @Path pattern and see if that helps.

Tips : I would suggest to test your service using postman chrome plugin to make sure if the Rest Service works well before trying to attempt to debug the service call 404 response issue from the .html file.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your advice but this error still here :( .My apache cxf url pattern /rest/* so my webapp running /rest/